# JdateChooser, como obtengo la fecha y como la envio a sql server

Tags: java, sql, jdatechooser

Estoy tratando de obtener la fecha de un JDateChooser para enviarla a una base de datos de SQL Server, pero el JDateChooser captura un formato de fecha distinto al que dice que debería mostrar (mmm dd, yyy), en lugar de eso muestra un formato de fecha que no es reconocible por SQL Server

Comment: ¿Qué formato no reconocible?

Comment: este es el formato que necesito: Nov 4, 2003 8:14 AM
Y este es el formato que el JDateChooser me devuelve: Tue Nov 04 08:14:00 EST 2003.  Entonces cuando lo envío al insert de SQL para almacenarlo me devuelve un error de String or Binary data would be truncated

Comment: [Lee esto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Ahí te explica cómo darle formato a las fechas en java. Después tienes qué averiguar qué formato está usando tu sql y convertirlo a ese formato. Creo que lo que muestras es solo una representación impresa.

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré a ver si logro resolverlo de esa forma.

Comment: Cuando tengas dudas (algo concreto) editas tu pregunta con todo el código para replicar el problema que puedas tener. No soy experto en en java, pero hay muchos usuarios muy buenos en ese lenguaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este código puedes pasar el Date del componente a sql.

```
Date date = ic.jDate.getDate(); //ic es la interfaz, jDate el JDatechooser
long d = date.getTime(); //guardamos en un long el tiempo
java.sql.Date fecha = new java.sql.Date(d);// parseamos al formato del sql
```

El atributo que debes mandar a la base de datos es **fecha**.

Si lo vas a guardar con hora tienes que usar `java.sql.Timestamp` y el campo en en tu base de datos debe ser tipo TimeStamp no Date.

Comment: Gracias, ese segmento de codigo ayudó mucho!!